# artifactory -- virtual debian repo release file is copy from first repo

Tags: debian, repository, virtual, artifactory

I have 3 local debian repos that I want to aggregate into one virtual repo. They have overlapping components. I have created a generic virtual repo and added the 3 local repos to it.

First question. Why is there no debian virtual repo type?

The Release and Release.gpg files in the vitual repo seem to be soft links (for lack of a better term) to the Release/Release.gpg files in the first real repo. I would expect artifactory to aggregate the 3 releases into a single file. But this does not seem to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away after I upgraded from Artifactory pro 5.5.0 to 6.5.2